# Uploading Add-In to 365 Admin Center - Deployment Failed - Next Steps?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

Update: We tried uploading the manifest from here --> https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/excel-shared-runtime-scenario which has all public URLs and works "as is" during my test sideload and is direct from Microsoft Devs and it still fails.

I have been building an Excel JavaScript Add-In for some time. I finally got IT to try and upload via 365 Admin Center, but this is the result.

The manifest passes validation.

The error is useless and I can't get permission to troubleshoot.

Any ideas what to try next?

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3214

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating a new sample add-in and deploy it there? Does it work correctly? If it works correctly, could you share your manifest?

Comment: I will try the simple deployment first using one of the GitHub examples from MSFT and report back @EugeneAstafiev

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I updated OP, tried w/ generic MSFT Manifest.xml and it still failed. Any idea where we could find logs?